# Change 2 values in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, replace, get, find

I've been beating myself up on this one all day and can't seem to figure it out... Here's my code real quick

```
C:\temp\biosconfigutility.exe --% /get:C:\temp\currentbios.txt
$bios = Get-Content C:\temp\currentbios.txt
$arr1 = [array]::IndexOf($bios, "TPM Device")
$arr2 = $arr1 + 1
$arr3 = $arr2 + 1
$bios[$arr3] -replace "\*Available", "Available"
$bios[$arr2] -replace "Hidden", "*Hidden"
```

So, I don't think I'm going about this in a way that makes sense or is necessarily efficient. But basically what's happening, is the first line generates a txt document that I need to programmatically change for roughly 10,000 PCs.

I need to find a way to make the changes seen at the bottom 2 lines and save that change to the overall array (the variable `$bios`).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem:

```
$bios[$arr3] -replace "\*Available", "Available"
```

does *not* update `$bios[$arr3]` with the result of the `-replace` operation - instead, it simply *outputs* the result.

Generally, **if you want the result of a `-replace` operation to *update a variable*, you must use an *assignment* with that variable as the LHS**, in *addition to* using it as an operand:

```
$bios[$arr3] = $bios[$arr3] -replace '\*Available', 'Available'
$bios[$arr2] = $bios[$arr2] -replace 'Hidden', '*Hidden'
```

---

Note that PowerShell has a shorthand notation for *some* operators for applying the operator to a variable *and* updating it with the result of the operation (e.g., `$v += 1` as shorthand for `$v = $v + 1`), but no such shortcut exists for `-replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out immediately after asking for help...

I changed the following:

```
$bios[$arr3] -Replace "\*Available","Available"
$bios[$arr2] -Replace "Hidden","*Hidden"
```

To:

```
$bios[$arr3] = "    Available"
$bios[$arr2] = "    *Hidden"
```

The first solution would replace the entire Array with just that one word, ruining the whole thing... But using the = sign, just that index called was changed, solving my problem

Comment: The commands in the first block _output_ the result of the replacement, without updating the array elements (or replacing the array as a whole). The commands in the second block do update the array elements, but simply by assigning a _fixed_ new value rather than deriving the new value from the old one by replacement.

Comment: I get what you're saying. Mklement0 provided a logical solution to that and I'm going to incorporate it into my code.

Comment: It was also I (mklement0) who posted the comment here. Unless my answer doesn't fully address your question (yet), can I suggest you accept it and delete this one?